# How to make Totals in access 2007

Tags: ms-access

My initial questions appears simple but a look at a table will show you my problem:

```
**Parts used    Model   Fleet # QTY in Stock    QTY used**
Oil filter     TLC 2010   A96         38         1
Oil filter     TLC 2010   A82         38         1
Air filter     TLC 2010   A96         24         1
Air filter     TLC 2010   A82         24         1
Fuel filter    TLC 2010   A96         30         1
```

How can I make totals for total Oil filter, air filter and fuel filter and then subtract these totals from my stock query?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT 
  s.PartsUsed, 
  s.SumOfQtyUsed, 
  q.QTYInStock, 
  [QTYInStock]-[SumOfQtyUsed] AS Result
FROM (
      SELECT 
        PartsUsed, 
        Sum(QTYUsed) AS SumOfQTYUsed
      FROM SampleData
      GROUP BY PartsUsed)  AS s 
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT 
        PartsUsed,
        QTYInStock 
      FROM SampleData)  AS q 
ON s.PartsUsed = q.PartsUsed
```

Comment: Please break this down for me; what do I do with what u have written?